# Why is it necessary to close a file after using it?

Tags: file-io

I read a question from a book that said "If the OS closes a file after the program terminates, why does the programmer need to close a file manually (i.e. call `file.close()`)?"

The only reason I could come up with is that the program may not terminate correctly, and so the file may be still open, therefore consuming system resources, because the file is kept on a buffer.

Are there any other reasons?

EDIT: I thought of another reason. Calling `file.close()` obliges the OS to flush to disk any changes that haven't been committed to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944666/why-must-i-close-a-file-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the programmer manually closes the file they have control over when/how the resources are released.

If it is left to the OS you cant be sure of when/if clean-up will take place, its generally bad practice as well.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations the program will call open so many times that it'll run out of file descriptors if they aren't released again.